# Sphinx AutoAPI extension enabled with adding README markdown files

Tags: templates, jinja2, markdown, extension-methods, python-sphinx

Python developers usually add `README.md` files to folders containing packages. They also want those files to be added to HTML documents generated by `Sphinx` (3.2.1 in my case) and the `sphinx_autoapi` extension (1.8.1 in my case). Can you please share your thoughts on possible solutions?

Comment: That's an awful lot of work when an [`include`](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#include) would suffice.

Comment: I thought about it and didn't choose this as a solution for the following reasons:
1. README can have big content to be included in a generated page.
2. Only 10% of sub-packages contain README.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'll follow this rule next time.

Answer (score 1):

1. In `conf.py`, add the `myst_parser` extension, that renders markdown files to HTML (I used the latest: 0.15.0), and create a function that checks if a needed file (this will be `README.md`) exists in a folder.

   ```
    extensions = [
        'autoapi.extension',
        'myst_parser',
        ...
    ]

    def local_file(name):
        return os.path.exists(name.lstrip('/'))

    def _prep_jinja_env(jinja_env):
        jinja_env.tests['loc_file'] = local_file

    autoapi_prepare_jinja_env = _prep_jinja_env
   ```

The `autoapi_prepare_jinja_env` variable extends a list of Jinja tests with one more test called 'loc_file'. This will be used in Jinja templates to check if a file named name exists in the current folder.

2. In the AutoAPI template, e.g., in `module.rst`, add the `toctree` directive that refers to the README page similar to this:

   ```
    {% if 'loc_file' in obj.jinja_env.tests %}
       {% set readme = obj.url_root + '/' + obj.pathname + '/README.md' %}
       {% if readme is loc_file %}

    .. toctree::
       :maxdepth: 1

       README

       {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
   ```

This will add a link to the README title (1st level header) if the `README.md` file exists in the current folder.

In addition to that, you will need a preprocessing (step #0) that collects all `README.md` files in the source Python package and copies them to the autoapi workspace before the main process (`Sphinx` + `autoapi`) starts. The `autoapi` extension doesn't touch any files in its workspace where it creates `*.rst` files.

When collecting `README.md` files, you need to create the same dir structure that the `autoapi` extension creates and that actually repeats the structure of the source Python package that you document.

That's it. It works as expected. I had to dive into the `autoapi` code to find it out for me.
Hope this helps others.